# How can I use function `SolveAlways` to solve this problem

Tags: differential-equations

Given that $y=\frac{1}{2} e^{2 x}+\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right) e^{x}$ is a special solution of the differential equation $y^{\prime \prime}+a y^{\prime}+b y=c e^{x}$ (`a`, `b`, `c` are constants), I want to find the value of `a`, `b`, `c`.

```
y[x_] := 1/2 E^(2 x) + (x - 1/3) E^x
SolveAlways[(D[#, {x, 2}] + a*D[#, x] + b*# == c*E^x) &@y[x], x]
```

But the above code can't solve this problem (the answer is `a=-3`,`b=2`,`c=-1`). How can I use function  `SolveAlways` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for `SolveAlways`:

> SolveAlways works primarily with linear and polynomial equations.

So let's make it linear!  There are three linearly independent functions in here, the constant function, $x$, and $e^x$, so let's set the exponential function to `y`:

```
y[x_] = 1/2 E^(2 x) + (x - 1/3) E^x;
(D[#, {x, 2}] + a*D[#, x] + b*# == c*E^x) &@y[x] // Simplify;
SolveAlways[% /. Exp[x] -> y, {x, y}];
(* {{a -> -3, b -> 2, c -> -1}} *)
```